# Rails default timestamps in PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

In rails created_at and updated_at timestamps are saved in the below format.
What is it "called" and how can I replicated it in PHP?

```
2011-07-21 15:34:58.885171+0000
```

Thankful for all input!

Comment: *(reference)* http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly that format is called, but PHP doesn't have a [predefined constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types) for it, so you need to create it yourself:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO')
```

I seem to vaguely remember that `.u` will always equal `.00000` in current PHP versions though.